# How can I flavor my ganache?

Tags: icing

I am trying to make an orange flavored ganache for an orange hostess cupcake. I'm thinking of using white chocolate chips but I'm afraid the orange flavoring and coloring will make the ganache clomp up. Has anyone tried this or have ideas on how it will work out?

Comment: Hmm- I was thinking dark chocolate orange (probably a lot of zest) and no need for color; Not sure how white will play, never tried ganache with it.

Comment: isn't Hostess a brand and not a style?

Comment: Why don't you add some Gran Marnier or Orange Liquor when making the ganache and whisk it in at the end when the white chocolate has melted.   Use a double boiled and I would whisk in the butter to get the sheen and then add the either of the Liquors off the heat. Take your time, whisk well and low heat and make sure no water gets in the pan as that will clomp up the mix.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you add enough liquid to the chocolate, it won't clomp up. This means you'll have to add your liquid flavoring to the cream and mix it well. Afterwards, make the ganache as any other white ganache, you shouldn't have any problems. Chips are even less likely to be a problem than real chocolate.